# Problems writing/compling generic Ninject binding

Tags: c#, generics, ninject, metaprogramming

I have the following class which I'm using to do a specific query on the database and creating a presentation model of data to pass back to the client browser.

```
public class SpecificFooQuery: IPresentationQuery<FooRequest, FooResult>
{
    public SpecificFooQuery(ILogger logger, DbContext context)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public FooResult Get(FooRequest request)
    {
        return new FooResult { ... };
    }
}
```

It implements the following generic interface

```
public interface IPresentationQuery<TRequest, TResult>
    where TRequest : class
    where TResult : class
{
    TResult Get(TRequest request);
}
```

But I'm having problems writing a ninject instantiation which will create my object for me.  This doesn't work but I've not really got any further than this so far.

```
kernel.Bind<IPresentationQuery<FooResult, FooRequest>>().To<SpecificFooQuery>();
```

Can anyone help me out with this, I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong or what I need to do to make this work.

---

```
Error   1   
The type 'SpecificFooQuery' cannot be used as type parameter 
'TImplementation' in the generic type or method   
'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingToSyntax<T1>.To<TImplementation>()'. 
There is no implicit reference conversion from 
'SpecificFooQuery' to 'IPresentationQuery<FooResult,FooRequest>'.
```

Comment: Nice to see how this design is quite similar as the design explained [here](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question is about Ninject, but if you're doing this kind of generic trickery, you might want to try [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/). It allows you to register all `IPresentationQuery<TRequest, TResult>` implementations in one single line of code like this:

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IPresentationQuery<,>),
    typeof(IPresentationQuery<,>).Assembly);
```

[RegisterManyForOpenGeneric](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Batch_Registration) is an extension method on the [SimpleInjector.Extensions](http://nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Extensions) project which can be downloaded from NuGet just as Simple Injector is.

And wrapping all those implementations with a generic decorator would also be a one-liner:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(IPresentationQuery<,>),
    typeof(ValidationPresentationQueryDecorator<,>));
```

Nice about Simple Injector is that it is blazingly fast, even when dealing with generic decorators. And Simple Injector even respects your generic type constraints. You add a generic type constraint to a decorator to prevent it from being wrapped to certain types. And if that's not possible, you can also register a conditional decorator like this:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(IPresentationQuery<,>),
    typeof(ValidationPresentationQueryDecorator<,>),
    context => NeedsValidation(context.ImplementationType));
```

Even this registration is optimized and the supplied predicate will only be called once per closed generic type. The [RegisterDecorator](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios#Generic_Decorators) method is part of the same Extensions project as `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric` is.

Comment: Do you have much experience with Simple Injector, I've done a few searches and saw it came top performance-wise in a test late last year.  We're running an MVC4/WebApi app and we're having some performance issues so I wonder if this might help us out a bit.

Comment: Some might say I've got some experience with Simple Injector :-). If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask here at Stackoverflow or at the Simple Injector code project forum.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the order of your type parameters is wrong. You try to bind `IPresentationQuery<FooResult, FooRequest>` to a implementation of `IPresentationQuery<FooRequest, FooResult>`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, still wouldn't work when I switched the request and results though.  ended up with the following line which worked `kernel.Bind(typeof(IPresentationQuery<FooRequest, FooReqult>)).To(typeof(SpecificFooQuery));`